mTLS authentication between two systems
This may be a basic question but looking to understand whats the best practice here.
Use case:
CompanyA and CompanyB wants to exchange information via REST API.
CompanyA (REST API provider) and CompanyB (is the client).
I was looking to adopt mTLS for the authentication between them to avoid passwords/api tokens etc.
CompanyA has a valid certificate signed by a CA (using a CA provider 1). (Not a self signed certificate).
CompanyB has a valid certificate signed by a CA (using a CA provider 1). (Not a self signed certificate).
Before opening up the API to the client, does their certificates (public keys) need to be mutually exchanged and set up in their stores? This appears to be a manual offline process to me?
Or is this dynamically requested and verified with the respective CA's as part of the handshake?
If this is a dynamic process, then no manual key exchange or set up needs to be done?
I'm not sure whats the working approach here.

This is obviously about PKI, which is better suited for [security.se]. Generally the PKI behind TLS will just use trusted (root) certificates from the CA as trust anchors to establish a trust path to the leaf certificates of the servers. After the TLS authentication the certificates are usually provided to the application which can be used to perform additional steps after the TLS connection has been setup. For more info about the verification process look up the X.509 RFC.
